# How to call RSS modified kimono API on demand?

Tags: rss, kimono

As you can see in the help ([goo.gl/JMlJgV](http://goo.gl/JMlJgV)) this is an ondemand call to obtain a JSON output:

```
http://kimonolabs.com/api/json/ondemand{API_ID}?apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This is for XML:

```
http://kimonolabs.com/api/json/ondemand{API_ID}?apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}&kimp‌​ath2=chipotle-new-york
```

What is for RSS on demand? And What is for a modified version?

Thank you

Comment: Please, details for "no result." Do you see a result for the non-kimmodify call API call? The URLs you posted are missing the API key so neither APIs return a result. There's not enough information in your question to help.

Comment: Hi @ValAsensio I have modified my question text.

Thank you

Comment: If they mention it's not working, then I think you're just lucky that the json version works for now. But it may be unwise to rely on the feature until they support it.